# Pact vs Spring Cloud Contract vs Karate

Tags: testing, karate, pact, contract, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to figure out the best tool for the contract testing. My scenario is quite simple. I have to implement contract testing specifically for front end talking to backend APIs.(client to REST APIs). I've done a POC on PACT already and I find PACT pretty useful, but I want to make sure I'm not missing out good features provided by other tools.

Major features I'm interested in from Pact:

1. can I deploy
2. Pending pacts when pact changes
3. webhooks

If you can please direct me to some valid reasons for considering or avoiding SCC or Karate, it would be really helpful.

Comment: dev of Karate here, I'll provide 3 references a) https://stackoverflow.com/a/64218355/143475 b) https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/consumer-driven-contracts c) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68037401/143475

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas, these links helped to clear the concept of karate as compared to pact.