How could Karate manage the 'stateful' mock in contract testing?
Based on Karate's example documentation, eventually, we'll use KC (payment-service.feature) and KP (payment-service-mock.feature) for testing. I have two questions:

Who defines KP? Is it defined by the producer or the consumer? If KP is defined by the consumer, the scenarios in KP might be significantly fewer than those in KC, leading to test failures due to missing mock scenarios. If KP is defined by the producer, it might not include the latest scenarios defined by the consumer, and thus issues may not be exposed.

How to address the problem of missing scenarios in KP? Should KC be layered, with different KPs defined by different consumers running different KCs? But this approach would require KC to be aligned with the consumers as well.


Is there some method to do the merge or split action?

Interesting question, I'll just give you my opinion.

I think the whole "consumer versus producer" concept is over-rated. The producer team "owns" the server and are responsible for writing tests that cover all that it can do. Isn't it that simple?
Are both teams in the same organization? Then just use the same Git repo and ask consumers to add any missing tests.
Else the producer team should publish the test-suite and the corresponding mock in an "open source" fashion. In reality, very few teams reach this level of maturity. You have to convince the team that they not only have to write tests, but the mock as well. It is also hard to get the buy in from consumer teams, for e.g. that they should actually use the mock and validate that their flows (contract) are not broken.
For what it is worth, it is possible to merge mock files into one, this was a community contribution, and you can see if it works for you.

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64218355/143475
